# How trigger Alexa alert from an lambda or external API

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

The main goal is to make Alexa speak each time defined text when lambda is triggered.

There already is one similar solution, "[Proactive Events Notifications](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/proactive-events-api.html)", but instead of activating yellow light on the dispositive, I need Alexa to say the defined message.

Also, I've seen the "[Skill Messaging API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/skill-messaging-api-reference.html)", but don't really understand if it is the solution.

Maybe you would help with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is not possible currently.

- **Notification**: Yes, the notification needs to be fetched proactively by the user.
- **Skill Messaging API**: Will **not** help you. Your skill can get informed about skill events and things the user do with his shopping and todo list. So you can subscribe to Events e.g.:

  - Skill events:

    - your skill is deactivated
    - an account was linked
    - skill permission accepted
    - ....
  - List events: the customer created/deleted a todo list item or a item from his shopping list
- [Reminder API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/alexa-reminders-api-reference.html): comes in directly but also not immediately. Maybe you could just set the reminder just some seconds after now and could simulate the effect of a direct message.

Comment: Very grateful for your response. According to the documentation, reminders can only be created directly from the device itself (In-session), and "Alexa Reminder API"(out of session) only allows you to read, modify and delete these reminders. And I need to manage reminders for each user individually from my API.

Comment: ah ok, thanks for clarification. Let's hope for something in the future.